# How to access browser shortcuts after using a Flash object?

Tags: browser, keyboard-shortcuts, flash

After using a flash control, browser shortcut keys are no longer available. To reproduce this:

- Access a page with a flash object in your favorite browser
- This is an example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4GMXavfKPY
- Click on play/pause
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> (should close the current tab)

**Is there any way to regain access to browser shortcuts after using a flash object?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the flash object was focused, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> didn't work. When I clicked outside the flash frame, then shortcuts worked as normal.

This was tested in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer 8

Comment: Indeed, this works, and is a partial solution. However it requires a precise click somewhere on the whitepace.

Comment: alternatively, a quick double Alt + TAB> will switch focus back to the browser, and you can then use the Ctrl + F4 shortcut

Comment: Seems there is no easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Plug-ins prevent shortcuts from work capturing everything, the only workaround I'm aware of is clicking outside [link](http://nusunt.eu/lang/en/browser-keyboard-shorcuts-not-working-with-flash-or-acrobat/).

NPAPI is being updated so maybe they will address this problem soon.